# Multiclassification task using keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

Classification (not detection!) of several objects in one image is the problem. How can I do this using keras.

For example if I have 6 classes (dogs,cats,birds,...) and two different objects (a cat and a bird) in this image. The label would be of the form: [0,1,1,0,0,0] Which metric, loss function and optimizer is recommended? I would like to use CNN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is "**multilabel classification**".
In the output layer you have multiple neurons, each neuron representing one of your classes.

Now you should use a binary classification for **each** neuron independently.
So if you have 3 classes, the output of your network could be [0.1, 0.8, 0.99] which means the following: The first class is true for your image with the probability 10 %, the second is true with 80 % and the last class is true with 99 %. So the network decided for two classes to be true at the same time for a single input image!

It's pretty easy to implement this into Keras/Tensorflow.
You could use some binary_crossentropy as your **loss function** and Sigmoid Function as the **activation** in your last layer. Therefore you get values in the interval (0, 1) for every output neuron.
As the **metric** you could use accuracy, which tells you how many images are classified in the right way (as relative frequency).

See the following example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.activations import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
import numpy as np

# put your data right here:
num_classes = 3 # here I'm assuming 3 classes, e.g. dog, cat and bird
x_train = np.zeros((100, 128, 128, 3)) # I'm just using zeros to simplify the example
y_train = np.zeros((100, num_classes))

model = Sequential()
# put your conv layer / conv blocks here:
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
    
model.compile(
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        optimizer=Adam(0.005),
        metrics=["accuracy"])
training_history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=5)
```

I'm using Tensorflow 2.2.0.
I hope this will help you :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I already tried these settings, there is also something not quite correct since the accuracy starts with around 90%. I think its measuring the accuracy in a wrong way. Some suggestions?

Comment: EDIT: I changed accuracy to categorical_accuracy. Now the accuracy stays around 2%

Comment: The value of the accuracy depends on your problem. The higher the accuracy the better your network works. accuracy should be the right choice because categorical_accuracy is suitable for a multiclass problem, where only one class is true. In our case we have a multiple binary class problem. I just worked on my project with this setting and it worked really well with accuracy.